# Tracking Ajax Add to Cart Event

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, addtocart, ajax, ecommerce-tracking

I have a problem I've been struggling for a couple of days and I would really like you to point me in the right direction. I am developing a module to track basic stuff like addToCart and ViewContent for the Facebook pixel.

The problem is, my module cannot track Ajax addToCart event using extensions like [this](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajaxcart-3-15606.html). I would really like you to give me some proper directions cause I feel like I am really lost in this one.

I tried updating layouts, adding my block on my observer event and much more. I'll pass some of my code below so you can get an idea of what I'm trying to do.

> config.xml

```
 <frontend>
<routers>
  <advertising>
    <use>standard</use>
    <args>
      <module>My_Advertising</module>
      <frontName>my</frontName>
    </args>
  </advertising>
</routers>
<events>
  <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <advertising>
            <class>advertising/observer</class>
            <method>myAddToCart</method>
        </advertising>
    </observers>
  </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
</events>
<layout>
  <updates>
    <advertising>
      <file>advertising.xml</file>
    </advertising>
  </updates>
</layout>
```

Observer function that I'm setting a variable for the product that has been added to cart

```
public function myAddToCart($observer)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->load(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product', 0));
    if (!$product->getId()) {
        return;
    }

    Mage::getModel('core/session')->setProductToShoppingCart(
        new Varien_Object(array(
            'id' => $product->getSku(),
            'name' => $product->getName(),
            'brand' => $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'),
            'price' => $product->getPrice(),
            'qty' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('qty', 1),
            'currency' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
        ))
    );
}
```

> layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
   <checkout_cart_add>
      <reference name="content">
        <block type="advertising/Mytracking" name="advertising_mytrackingcart" template="advertising/mytrackingcart.phtml">
        </block>
         </reference>
      </checkout_cart_add> 
      </layout>
```

> mytrackingcart.phtml

```
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('core/session')->getProductToShoppingCart(); ?>
   <?php if ($product && $product->getId()): ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        echo $this->myGetAddToCartFacebook($product); 
       </script>
<?php Mage::getModel('core/session')->unsProductToShoppingCart(); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

> My block function

```
 public function myGetAddToCartFacebook()
    {
        $id = $product['id'];
        $price = number_format($product['price'], 2);
        $currency = $product['currency'];
        $code = "fbq('track', 'AddToCart', { value: \"{$price}\",currency: \"{$currency}\",content_ids: [\"{$id}\"],content_type: 'product' });";
        return $code;
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?  Are you not seeing the tracking info after using the Ajax add to cart functionality?  Is the tracking code not being displayed on the next page after adding the product?  Are you having issues when adding multiple different products to the cart via Ajax from the category page?

Comment: Did you consider having the tracking events sent `onclick` *before* the actual add to cart happens?

Answer (score -1):

```
public function myAddToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->load(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product', 0));
    if (!$product->getId()) {
        return;
    }

    Mage::getModel('core/session')->setProductToShoppingCart(
        new Varien_Object(array(
            'id' => $product->getSku(),
            'name' => $product->getName(),
            'brand' => $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'),
            'price' => $product->getPrice(),
            'qty' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('qty', 1),
            'currency' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
        ))
    );
}
```

Replace this with your observer function.

**Hope it will help**

Comment: Can you expand your answer please?  Give context to your code and why that code would work versus the code posted by OP.  How does this solve the problem of tracking adding to cart via AJAX?